# How to pass parameters to APOC query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to query records (between certain period) from SQL DB using APOC library. When I pass the from & to dates as parameters I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
String queryString ="CALL apoc.load.jdbc('mssql',\"select * from table as tb where tb.from_Date >= {fromDate} AND tb.to_Date <= {endDate} \") YIELD row";

String fromDate = "2018-11-12 00:00:00";
String endDate = "2018-11-13 00:00:00";
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("fromDate", fromDate);
parameters.put("endDate", endDate);

StatementResult result = tx.run(queryString, parameters);
```

I get below errors:

If I use syntax `{}`

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure 
`apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'.
```

If I use syntax `$`

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure 
`apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid pseudocolumn "$fromDate".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your version, the parameters placeholders are just part of the query string and they value are not passed.

So use the [`apoc.load.jdbcParams`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_jdbc_with_params_examples) procedure like this:

```
String query = "CALL apoc.load.jdbc('mssql', {sql}, [{fromDate}, {endDate}]) YIELD row return row";
String sql = "select * from table as tb where tb.from_Date >= ? AND tb.to_Date <= ?";
String fromDate = "2018-11-12 00:00:00";
String endDate = "2018-11-13 00:00:00";

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("sql", sql);
parameters.put("fromDate", fromDate);
parameters.put("endDate", endDate);

StatementResult result = tx.run(query, parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using jdbcParams I was able to pass the params and query

Comment: @ManojChikkala Do not forget to accept the answer if you solved your problem with it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers